Sending SMS using HTTP requests
I need to integrate SMS into my web site. Could you share the gateway? It will be better if API includes several delivery channels and methods for multi-channel routing.
We can't continue using our previous provider due to low performance.

We use multichanel routing WhatsApp—SMS via Messaggio. They work worldwide, provide up to 7000 rps, that’s good for our volumes.  HTTP/S, SMPP, SMTP are available.
Specification with request samples: https://messaggio.com/api-docs/

Checkout Twillio SMS API. It is by far the most popular according to this blog post.
Other alternatives include

Vonage SMS API
TextBetter SMS API
Telnyx SMS API

Here is a blog post describing them and other options.
